# Excel VBA Pass Id of Value in Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, identifier

Looking for advice on the best way to pass an Id of a value into a parameter in excel VBA.

Essentially I'm trying to replicate getting the value rather than the text itself like for example in html:

```
<option value="1">Option one</option>
```

Would return 1. I could concatenate the Id to the start or end of the string with something like:

```
.additem varList(0, 1) & " | " & varList(1, 1)
```

But I'm looking for a 'cleaner' option if that makes sense?

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, but to me its unclear what youre asking.

Comment: This isnt clear at all. Can you give more of a context?

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to articulate what I mean! So the combobox is filled with values from a table in a database. When the form is submitted, I'm looking for the Id from the table to be submitted rather than the related value - does this help?

Comment: not really. How are you retrieving the `ID of a value`?

Comment: Through ADO returning the recordset into a variant and then looping through the values in the variant to fill the combobox. The variant is loaded with the ID and the value.

Comment: Gareth - thanks for this question.  I'm over four years late to it, but it makes perfect sense and David Zemens explanation was perfect.  As a frequent ADO user, this method is far better than using the visualized text in a combobox for my 'WHERE' clause.  BIG + 1 to you and David! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your combobox with at least 2 columns. This can be set using the `ColumnCount` property, via the VBE or through VBA code.

[image]

You can then adjust the `ColumnWidths` property to make one of the columns a width of 0 so it will not be displayed/visible to users.

WHen you populate the combobox, simply put the ID in one column of the ComboBox, and put the value in the other visible column.  The interface will look like this, unless you adjust the columnwidths

[image]

Use the `BoundColumn` of the ComboBox to return the appropriate value, or you can do some iteration over the *selected* item(s) and refer to the indexed position:

```
Debug.Print Me.ComboBox.List(0, 0)  '# Display the first row item in the first column

Debug.Print Me.ComboBox1.List(0, 1)  '# Display the first row item in the SECOND column
```

Comment: Thanks @David Zemens, that's perfect! Thanks for managing to understand the questions as well!

Comment: How do you insert a row with two columns. I tried `.AddItem "CO", "Cam Operation"` but it returned "Non-correspondent type". I was trying to use CO as ID. Is it possible?

Comment: The `.AddItem` method takes two arguments: *value* and *column*.  You cannot use the `.AddItem` method to add multiple columns. Instead, you can use it to add the *first* column, and then specify the second column's value with the `.List` method.  Example: `.AddItem("CO", 0)` and then `.List(0, 1)` = "Cam Operation"`